# Do runes override the base effect?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I use [punish](http://diablo.somepage.com/crusader/active/punish) and I use a rune with it, do I still get the 15% increased block rate or does the rune perk replace that? For instance, if I use Celerity, do I get 15% block rate increase *and* 15% attack speed increase or just the AS increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. In this case, you still get the 15% increased block rate, but some runes do completely replace the effect with a new one.

For example [Zombie Charger](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/zombie-charger)'s Pile On rune removes the zombie that you'd get normally, completely changing the spell.

The best way to check is to just try it out. Carefully reading skills can help you make an educated guess, but some quick science will remove all doubt. Changing your skill build is free, after all.